# WSO2 ESB Aggregate Mediator sending more messages out than the the number that was sent out

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have built an API that sends messages to multiple endpoints using clone mediator. I have also used an aggregate mediator to collect the messages that are returned by the endpoints to one message and send it back to the client. 
Below is the outsequence that has the aggregate mediator:

```
        <outSequence>
        <aggregate id="GetOpenTasksReq">
            <completeCondition>
                <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="//jsonObject" xmlns:m0="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                <log level="custom" separator=",">
                    <property name="MessageFlow" value="======================= Sending Back the Aggregated Responses. ==============="/>
                </log>
                <log level="full" separator=","/>
                <enrich>
                    <source clone="true" xpath="//tasks"/>
                    <target action="child" type="body"/>
                </enrich>
                <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
                <send/> 
            </onComplete>
        </aggregate>
        <send/> 
    </outSequence>
```

It was supposed to return

```
    {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "desc": "New Assignment Item",
      "due": "2019-02-18T06:23:41+07:00",
      "link": "https://[host]:[port]/viewtask?id=10"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "desc": "New Assignment Item",
      "due": "2019-02-18T06:23:41+07:00",
      "link": "https://[host]:[port]/viewtask?id=1"
    },
    {
      "id": 33,
      "desc": "New Assignment Item",
      "due": "2019-02-18T06:23:41+07:00",
      "link": "https://[host]:[port]/viewtask?id=33"
    }
  ]
}
```

But instead I got :

```
    {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "desc": "New Assignment Item",
      "due": "2019-02-18T06:23:41+07:00",
      "link": "https://[host]:[port]/viewtask?id=10"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "desc": "New Assignment Item",
      "due": "2019-02-18T06:23:41+07:00",
      "link": "https://[host]:[port]/viewtask?id=10"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "desc": "New Assignment Item",
      "due": "2019-02-18T06:23:41+07:00",
      "link": "https://[host]:[port]/viewtask?id=1"
    },
    {
      "id": 33,
      "desc": "New Assignment Item",
      "due": "2019-02-18T06:23:41+07:00",
      "link": "https://[host]:[port]/viewtask?id=33"
    }
  ]
}
```

For some reasons one of the response from one of the endpoints gets repeated. I have tried retriggering the request to the API on the ESB but it would always repeat one of the reponses. Can you kindly help me by looking at my aggregate mediator configuration and see if there is any error? As usual thanks in advance.

Comment: Difficult to say as I can't see what the insequence and the iterate is doing and what the endpoints are returning. I do notice that your aggegrate is in the outsequence. What could be the cause is that the aggegrated messages are added to the original message that triggered the outSequence. You might try aggegrating in the insequence.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your Enrich mediator is making the problem. To make it clear I try to explain an example, it is not exactly how `Aggregator` works but it may clear the reason for the problem. By receiving the first response it Enriches the `//tasks` to the `body`. By receiving the second response, again it does the same, as you may guess, `body` is already has something in it under the `//tasks` so in the second time it aggregates two `//tasks`.

It is better to use another property instead of enriching the body.

Comment: It is now working as I wanted it . What I did was to change the  clone> value to "false". Now the enrich mediator looks like                         <enrich>
                        <source clone="false" xpath="//tasks"/>
                        <target action="child" type="body"/>
                    </enrich>

Comment: There seems to be a dearth of materials on the aggregate mediator and the scatter and gather implementation in the WSO2 official site.

Comment: If the answer was true, mark it as the answer @user2749166